# Identify a sybase created procedure that has missing procedure

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

> Error  : Cannot add rows to sysdepends for the current stored procedure because it depends on the missing object 'P_PROCTEST. The stored procedure will still be created.

The cause of this error is because  of missing another procedure, however it will be created.

This query will shows the existing procedures in the database but how can I know which of them have missing procedures ?

> select * from sysprocedures

Answer (score 0):

you could check if the stored procedures are missing before creating the new one:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.<sp_name>') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  xxxx
END
```

Comment: in my scenario there alreay procedures already been.actually I dont know all the missing procedures

Comment: for the stored procedures for which you got errors during the creation, you could search for the pattern "exec xxx" to identify the sub-stored procedures and check if they exist in the table sysprocedures

Comment: I dont know all the missing procedures . they are alot @vince

Comment: normally to know dependencies between objects we have to look at the table sysdepends (or the SP "sp_depends") but your error message says that this table has not been updated. It looks like there is no automatic way to detect the missing SPs other than going manually in each SP code